# Get temporary download url via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I created a PHP file which forces a file download.
When I call it via ajax it won't work.
Google says ajax can't handle downloads.
I should just open a new window directing to the url.

The problem is the file does only exists while the php script is running.
So how do I get around this problem ?

Here is the code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $jsonStr = $_POST['jsonStr'];

    $tmp_file = tempnam('/tmp', 'data-');
    $handle = fopen($tmp_file, 'a+');
    fwrite($handle, $jsonStr);

    if(!$tmp_file)
    {
        // File doesn't exist, output error
        die('file not found');
    }
    else
    {
        // Set headers
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=iwbtg.lvl");
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        // Read the file from disk
        readfile($tmp_file);
    }
?>
```

JS:

```
...

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

// Request Level file
var http = createRequestObject();
http.open("POST", "save.php", false);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www.form-urlencoded");
http.send("jsonStr=" + jsonStr);


document.location = "tmp/iwbtg.lvl";
```

Comment: Don't use ajax, in that case. If you must, then have the ajax server-side script send back the url which does the actual download, and have your client-side script open a new window with that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ajax you could use an [iframe](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/post-data-to-an-iframe/). This is not pretty but works well. You do the post to the iframe and that will not reload the whole page which is what i guess you are trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Yeah but how do I open the php file and pass POST values at the same time ?

Comment: Your best bet is to set the form to post to the iframe. Check out this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/post-data-to-an-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to lock the UI or open a new window (because the action takes time), you can do it with a hidden iframe:

```
var downloadAsync = function(url, callback) { 
    var f = document.createElement('iframe'); 
    f.style.display = 'none'; 
    f.src = url; 
    f.onload = function() { 
        setTimeout(function() { 
            document.body.removeChild(f); 
        }, 500); 
        callback && callback(); 
    }; 
    document.body.appendChild(f); 
};
```

just make sure that the server responds with the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.